# Find two elements in a matrix that equal a number, m, through equation f(x,y)

Tags: matlab

I'm fairly new to coding, in general, and new to matlab completely, so I apologize for the lack of technical terms. Basically, I'm trying to find the two numbers, one in each for loop, that equal m through the equation f(x,y) (if it exists), then separate the two elements back into the inputs, so they can be used later.

```
% example code
nr = 1;
nc = 2;
inputs = zeros(nr,nc);
m =  1000;    %example number
for x = 1:n
    for y = 1:n
        f(x,y) = (y.^2 .* cos(x).^2) ./ tan(x);
        if f(x,y) == m
            inputs = [f(x), f(y)];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What are the values of the `n` and `a` variables?

Comment: 'a' was supposed to be 'x' and 'n' is just arbitrary for the example.

Comment: Are the two loops to loop through the rows and columns of your matrix `inputs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood what you want.

You can use the [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function. So after the loop is done you could do this for instance:

```
nr = 1;
nc = 2;
inputs = zeros(nr,nc);
m =  1000;    %example number
for x = 1:nr
    y = 1:1:nc;
    f(x,:) = (y.^2 * cos(x)^2) / tan(x);        
end
 
[rows, col] = find(f == m);
inputs = [rows, col];
```

Note that it then needs to be exactly the same. However, with sines, cosines, tans, it might be difficult to actually set that correct value for `m`

EDIT removed the inner loop of y, that is not necessary if you only want successive integer values for y

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Good point about the sine, cosines, and tans. Would it be possible to do an approximation of m?

Comment: You could do `find(f >= m - ToleranceVal && f <= m + ToleranceVal)`.

Comment: Not only is `f==m` difficult because of the sine, cosines and tans. Floating-point arithmetic is approximate by definition. A plain old division or multiplication can cause exact equality to be impossible.

Comment: Very true indeed